# RegEx Notepad++ Python Script to change Date Format

Tags: python, regex, date

Gang...I need a notepad++ python script teaching moment.

I want to find and replace a date format (`MM/DD/YY` and replace with `YYYY-MM-DD`).  In NotePad++ RegEx I can do this with

```
Find: (([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+))

Replace: 20\3-\1-\2
```

Would someone show me a notepad++ python script that will accomplish the same thing?  I think my knowledge gap is in group replacement

Answer (score 0):

If you speek of [Python Script for Notepad++](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/) there is

```
# Regular expressions search and replace
editor.rereplace(r"^([A-Z]{3,5})--\1", r"CODE: \1")
```

on that page.

Comment: Yep...thats it..funny...I have been trying to fix all day....I write the question...the bang I figured this out...weird...thanks...

Comment: Here is the snip: 

editor.rereplace(r'([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)', r'20\3-\1-\2')

Comment: From Npp import *  
    import re  
    
    # Start a sequence of actions that is undone and redone as a unit. May be nested.  
    editor.beginUndoAction()  
    
    editor.rereplace(r'([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)', r'20\3-\1-\2')  
    
    # end the undo sequence  
    editor.endUndoAction()

Answer (score 0):

Finds MM/DD/YY and Replaces with YYYY-MM-DD adds leading zeros
NotePad++ PythonScript and RegEdit

```
from Npp import *
import re

editor.beginUndoAction()

editor.rereplace(r'([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)/+([0-9]+)', r'20\3-\1-\2')
editor.rereplace(r'([0-9]{4})-+([0-9]{1})-+([0-9]{2})', r'\1-0\2-\3')
editor.rereplace(r'([0-9]{4})-+([0-9]{2})-+([0-9]{1} )', r'\1-\2-0\3')
editor.rereplace(r'([0-9]{4})-+([0-9]{1})-+([0-9]{1})', r'\1-0\2-0\3' )

editor.endUndoAction()
```